# add php echo year to existing variable

Tags: php, echo

How do I add a echo `date("Y")` to the `$creds` variable?  I have tried a bunch of different ways and it blows it up, what is the proper syntax?

```
$creds = 'Copyright &copy; &middot; by <a href="http://w#" target="_blank">#</a>';
return $creds;
```

Comment: What the heck, why did you downgrade my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concat operator in PHP is `.` (period).

You can concat two strings together like:

```
echo 'Hello' . '-' . 'World'; // Hello-World

$world = 'World';
echo 'Hello' . '-' . $world; // Hello-World

$hello = 'Hello';
$world = 'World';
$hello_world = $hello . $world;
echo $hello_world; // HelloWorld
```

In your example:

```
$creds = 'Copyright &copy; &middot; by <a href="http://w#" target="_blank">#</a>' . date("Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$creds = 'Copyright &copy; &middot; by <a href="http://w#" target="_blank">#</a>';
return $creds . date("Y");
```